# How do I prevent people from seeing my transactions and the information about these transactions?

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool, sendtransaction, private, sendsignedtransaction

I don't want to expose my pending transactions to the public mempool b/c I want to prevent arbitrage and tactics like frontrunning.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to send a private transaction by using "`eth_sendPrivateTransaction`". This sends the transaction privately through Flashbots -- it won't be included in the public mempool for everyone to see. If they can't see it, they can't take advantage of it by acting on the information within the transaction as easily.

You can use various RPC providers's private transactions endpoints for this -- for example, create an [account](https://alchemy.com) and then enter in the following:

[image]

Btw if your transaction hasn't been mined yet (aka it hasn't gone through successfully by being pulled from the mempool and added to a block), you can use "`eth_cancelPrivateTransaction`"

For more info, check out [eth_sendPrivateTransaction](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-sendprivatetransaction) and [the general Transact API page](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/transact-api-quickstart).